# Log into another SharePoint site as current user?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, oauth

I have a provider hosted app connected to a SharePoint site. I want to write some code that allows the provider hosted app to create/get data on a different sharepoint site. I read articles that imply OAUTH should let this all happen, but I cant get it to work. Here's my code that doesnt work

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
string userAccessToken = spContext.UserAccessTokenForSPHost;
UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(userAccessToken);
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/siteA.onmicrosoft.com", false);
ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential("clientID", "clientSecret");
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://siteB.sharepoint.com", clientCred,userAssertion)
```

Comment: are you get any error in the above code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this kind of code works in SharePoint. I think you need to use OAuthAuthorize.aspx to get an oauth token for the current user on a different sharepoint instance.

lots of articles how to use OAuthAuthorize.aspx, this is one of them

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2015/01/27/connecting-to-sharepoint-from-an-office-app/